# Run ios from flutter

Tags: ios, flutter

I have app I wrote its code by dart on Android studio flutter I test it on Android simulator and it worked but I can't test ios version I had already installed VMware and made a virtual machine from mac but I can't connect it with Android studio

Answer (score 1):

For running the App on iOS simulator. You need to follow these things:

1. Follow [Bilaal](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7630779/bilaal-abdel-hassan)'s advice and install XCode.
2. Now after you are done, go to the project folder from `Terminal` or `Command Prompt`. Type `open -a simulator`, this opens up a iOS simulator for you.
3. Run `flutter run`

I hope that would help you in great extent.

Answer (score 0):

For IOS, you need to run your codes using [Xcode](https://developer.apple.com/xcode/)

Answer (score 0):

Download the iPhone x simulator and make sure you have xcode up and running